# Change Div Class with Javascript if DateTime variable is passed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Good Morning, I have Written a Dashboard for work written in PHP and Javascript. It pulls Data from our database and shows events in Divs with a class of Dash, Showing a Variable of $nextupdate, I need to write some Js that will compare the DateTime Now and if the $nextupdate variable time is past then i need to change the Div Class to .overdue, I am struggling to figure out how would be the best way to solve this

any help would be much appreciated

Regards

Steve

Comment: help would be provided if we can see your code

Comment: Give snippet to have better idea.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in JS on the front end? If you have a php variable why not use strtotime() to convert it to an integer, then get current time and simply compare which is larger. Then use this in an if condition to add your class where needed. If there is a reason you can't do it this way please post your code and explain why the need to do it in JS. Also are you using a library - jquery, angular etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$nextupdate; // got from the database
$now = date();
$divClass = "";
if(strtotime($now) > strtotime($nextupdate) ){
    $divClass="overdue";
}else{
    $divClass="whatever";
}
```

and then :

```
<div class="<?php echo $divClass; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that actually worked... I had forgotten to change Server Timezone to London... Cheers for all your help

Answer (score 0):

That works Great for changing the Div colour to red when overdue, Although i didnt explain that i have Multiple Divs...

Here is my Code for the Div

```
    //Gather all Posted HPi tickets raised
$sql = "Select *
From hpi_calls 
where status!='Closed'
and (Priority='P1' or Priority='M1')
order by NextUpdate Asc";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$statuslist = "";



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $SR = $row["SR"];
$Priority = $row["Priority"];
$Customer = $row["Customer"];
$BDescription = $row["BDescription"];
$Team = $row["Team"];
$Engineer = $row["Engineer"];
$OpenTime = $row["OpenTime"];
$Status = $row["Status"];
$LastUpdate = $row["LastUpdate"];
$NextUpdate = $row["NextUpdate"];
$Owner = $row["Owner"];
$FDescription = $row["FDescription"];
$ASites = $row["ASites"];
$LoggingTeam = $row["LoggingTeam"];
$OwningTeam = $row["OwningTeam"];
$FUpdate = $row["FUpdate"];
$Supplier = $row["Supplier"];

$NextUpdate;
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$divClass = "";
if(strtotime($now) > strtotime($NextUpdate) ){
    $divClass="Overdue";
}else{
    $divClass="Dash";
}


    $statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$SR.'" class=" '.$divClass.'"><h2>'
            .$SR.'</h2><h2>'.$Customer.'</h2><h2>'.$Priority.'</h2> - '.$Status.'<br><h2>Next Update Due:<br>'.$NextUpdate.'</h2></div>';
               } 




}
```

The above is the Complete code for selecting from the DB and posting to the Divs

Regards

Steve